# Resolving generic Decorators with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, decorator, simple-injector

I am trying to build out a structure where I have a base IValidator<> interface that will be generated for our system based on some metadata. We want to give future developers the flexibility to 1) Regenerate the concrete implementations of IValidator<> if need be without disturbing any hand-written code and 2) Add decorators to IValidator<> to be able to extend the functionality without disturbing the auto-generated code.

I would like to have some way to resolve the generic decorators at runtime using the RegisterDecorator method of Simple Injector so our dev team does not need to go and update the composition root every time we add a decorator.

Here are some example classes/interfaces

```
public interface IValidator<T> where T : class
{
    void Validate(T entity);
}
public class ClientValidator : IValidator<Client>
{
    public void Validate(Client entity)
    {
        //Auto-generated
    }
}
public class UserValidator : IValidator<User>
{
    public void Validate(User entity)
    {
        //Auto-generated
    }
}
public class ClientValidatorDecorator : IValidator<Client> 
{
    private readonly IValidator<Client> clientValidator;

    public ClientValidatorDecorator(IValidator<Client> clientValidator)
    {
        this.clientValidator = clientValidator;
    }
    public void Validate(Client entity)
    {
        //New rules
        this.clientValidator.Validate(entity);
    }
}
public class UserValidatorDecorator : IValidator<User>
{
    private readonly IValidator<User> userValidator;

    public UserValidatorDecorator(IValidator<User> userValidator)
    {
        this.userValidator = userValidator;
    }
    public void Validate(User entity)
    {
        //New rules
        this.userValidator.Validate(entity);
    }
}
public class ValidationContext
{
    private readonly IValidator<Client> client;
    private readonly IValidator<User> user;

    public ValidationContext(IValidator<Client> client, IValidator<User> user)
    {
        this.client = client;
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

We I am trying to do something like so:

```
public void RegisterServices(Container container)
{
    container.Register(typeof(IValidator<>), AssemblyManifest.GetAssemblies());
    container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IValidator<>), GetType, Lifestyle.Transient, UseType);
}
private static Type GetType(DecoratorPredicateContext ctx)
{
    //Return appropriate Decorator
}
private static bool UseType(DecoratorPredicateContext ctx)
{
    //Predicate
}
```

Unfortunately, unless I resolve a concrete type RegisterDecorator throws an error, so resolving another generic seems out. I am not sure how to proceed. Is there a way to do something like this? Is there a better way to get the intended functionality without decorators? We were thinking partial classes, but that has its own set of issues.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than plugging in decorators you could use a *Composite Validator* to enable the addition of `IValidator<>` implementations as required. This solution would allow the code to contain multiple `IValidator<>`'s for the same type.

Internally your code will still be able to depend on a single `IValidator<T>` which would resolve to the `CompositeValidator` that would call zero or more validators depending on what has been registered in the container at runtime.

The composite validator:

```
public class CompositeValidator<T> : IValidator<T>
{
    public readonly IEnumerable<IValidator<T>> validators;

    public CompositeValidator(IEnumerable<IValidator<T>> validators)
    {
        this.validators = validators;
    }

    public void Validate(T item)
    {
        foreach(var validator in this.validators)
        {
            validator.Validate(item);
        }
    }
}
```

The container is configured like this:

```
var assemblies = new[] { typeof(IValidator<>).Assembly };
var container = new Container();
container.RegisterCollection(typeof(IValidator<>), assemblies);
container.Register(typeof(IValidator<>), typeof(CompositeValidator<>));
```

where the `assemblies` variable contains all the assemblies you want to search for validators.

When you resolve `IValidator<User>` using `container.GetInstance<IValidator<User>>()` or through constructor injection you get back `CompositeValidator<User>` which internally references any and all  `IValidator<User>`'s.

Comment: This is a great resolution! I will run it by the team! Thanks!

Comment: How do you ensure the order this way?

Comment: The only bad thing about this style is that it would no longer chain the calls.  If all Validates are equal, you are fine, but if you had a CommandHandlerValidator<> that is wrapping a ICommandHandler<>, this style wouldn't work.

Comment: I wanted this CompositeValidator to actually be a decorator so that it would run before the actual command.  Thus, I just had to change this slightly but this style does end up working for me in the end!

Answer (score 2):

The way to get decorators of a type using batch registration is by calling the `GetTypesToRegister` method overload that accepts a `TypesToRegisterOptions` object. This way you can instruct SI to return decorators as well.

```
container.Register(typeof(IValidator<>), assemblies);

var t1 = container.GetTypesToRegister(typeof(IValidator<>), assemblies);
var t2 = container.GetTypesToRegister(typeof(IValidator<>), assemblies,
    new TypesToRegisterOptions { IncludeDecorators = true });

foreach (Type t in t2.Except(t1)) {
    container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IValidator<>), t);
}
```

Do note that I do not suggest using this code. @qujck's answer addresses the design issue you have with your code, and his solutions therefore brings you to a much better place.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Regardless of if it is the best solution I do like to know as much as possible about the tools I am using, so this is still valuable information.

Comment: This works pretty well.  However, like above, how can you force a certain order?  Thanks!

Comment: @DanielLorenz by sorting them. Try `Enumerable.OrderBy`.

Comment: @Steven What I sort by would probably need to be some sort of attribute I can look up on the type, I assume?  Can't go by the name, obviously. :)

Comment: Ah, now I see why you liked the above style better.  Though, they would no longer be considered Decorator only types by SI, so you could get into trouble in certain scenarios?

Comment: @Steven Ah wait, actually, your style is going to actually work for me as I'm wrapping multiple ICommandHandler<>.  One that handles any exceptions that get thrown, and then another that validates the Command.  They have to be called in a chain, so the other answer won't work for me.

Comment: I generally do not advice batch-registering decorators, since their order is important and they are few in number. Just register them one-by-one, that guarantees their order and makes it easy to follow what's going on.

Comment: @Steven Actually, mine is a little bit different.  I wanted to mass register  Command validators that exist.  They would all be in the same order.  However, you can't have a generic version that handles them all since they are command specific.  Thus, I would want to mass register them, but then I'd only select the ones that are that type of interface to ensure the order is correct.

Comment: Hi Daniel, it's hard to say anything useful here through this commenting channel. If you want some quality help and feedback, please post a question with details of your design on [the forum](https://simpleinjector.org/forum). Multiple skilled people with a good understanding of design and SI are watching it.